# docker server can not find main class

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, docker

I have an issue on a spring-boot+ mysql+ react js application that is functional.( I have tested it before trying to deploy it on docker).

When I give the command "docker-compose up -d" it works, i can see the containers, I can acces the frontend but any requests make in the backend/server are refused.

I looked through the server logs and  get the error:  `Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.springdemo.SpringDemoApplication`

My dockerfile:

```
#### Stage 1: Build the application
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as build

# Set the current working directory inside the image
WORKDIR /app

# Copy maven executable to the image
#COPY mvnw .
#COPY .mvn .mvn

# Copy the pom.xml file
COPY pom.xml .

# Build all the dependencies in preparation to go offline. 
# This is a separate step so the dependencies will be cached unless 
# the pom.xml file has changed.
#RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline -B

# Copy the project source
COPY src src

# Package the application
#RUN ./mvnw package -DskipTests
#RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)

#### Stage 2: A minimal docker image with command to run the app 
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

#ARG DEPENDENCY=/app/target/dependency

# Copy project dependencies from the build stage
#COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
#COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
#COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.example.springdemo.SpringDemoApplication"]
```

I checked and the path to the main *is correct* . I have no idea why it doesn't find the main class.

The backend code is at : https://github.com/Diana-Ioana/docker_app allong with docker-compose.yml file and the Dockerfile for the backend. 
I use docker toolbox( not docker desktop, I have WIN 10 HOME)

Comment: This might be stupid but aren't you forgetting a slash on this line: "COPY src src"?
Also, what happens if you comment out the last line of the dockerfile and replace it with a stub, then shell into the container and manually run the command? I have had similar issues where my code was not in place but not failing either.

Comment: In your final stage there aren't any uncommented `COPY` lines, so you're running the unmodified JRE image.  Do you actually `COPY` the built jar file or class files from the build image?  Similarly, do you actually build the application (you've commented out `RUN ./mvnw package`)?

Comment: The Dockerfile was auto generated when running ```mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper``` for the .mvn so I imagined that this is how it should look, I did not modify anything.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you copy sources only,  so although all paths are correct, there is nothing to call "java" on (it should be called on .class or .jar if -jar is specified).

If you are new to docker/spring boot, spring io has a very good guide for running spring boot in docker, so it is worth checking out: [Spring Boot with Docker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)

Comment: Will look into it. The Dockerfile was auto-generated from th ``` mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper ``` command and I didn't modify anything